How do I know which command slot caused the interrupt in AHCI?
When I was learning AHCI, I found that I could tell which port caused the interrupt by using the PI register. However, a port has multiple command slots, which register should I query to find out which command slot the interrupt came from?
I would like to know how interrupt handling is done in an AHCI driver. If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful.
